# UITextField clearsOnInsertion does not working

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I set

```
textField.clearsOnInsertion=YES
```

but nothing happened. I am using `XCode 5.0` and `iOS 7.0`

Comment: What did you expect to happen? There is nothing wrong with that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should firstly make it clear what is `clearsOnInsertion`. See Apple's doc:

> **clearsOnInsertion**
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether inserting text
>   replaces the previous contents.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The default value of this property is NO. When the value of
>   this property is YES and the text view is in editing mode, the
>   selection UI is hidden and inserting new text clears the contents of
>   the text view and sets the value of this property back to NO.

`clearsOnInsertion` is very useless in my opinion. See the screenshot:
[image]

The text field is in editing mode and the keyboard is shown but the selection UI is hidden. When you input any thing, it will replace the old text. That's it.

Another related useful property is `clearsOnBeginEditing`

> **clearsOnBeginEditing**
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the text field removes old text when editing begins.

Comment: well in using clearsOnInsertion, the text I wrote, appended in the previous text but didn't replace it.

Comment: @shankywave1, See my updated answer for what it is in example.

Comment: @sunkeyhappy, I understand the difference now. But how could selectionUI not showing? In my case selection UI is showing and when I write something in it, text get appended rather than replacing. I hope you understand this.

Comment: What I have done is add the `UITextField` in the .xib file and set its text to `dasfgfd`. Then the app run you tap the text field, the selection UI will not show. Second time, it will show.

Comment: I suppose the main problem was that the property was re-setting to NO after each edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear previous text when editing begins you should use
`textfield.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES`